# "when he is not playing/ when he doesn't play"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> He will probably win (once or twice more/again) the fans favourite **when he is not playing/ when he doesn't play.**

Is it possible to use both "when he is not playing"/"when he doesn't play"? Most importantly could you tell me the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

*present simple* is often used with a future meaning. When dealing with subordinated clauses (in the present case *when*).

In your example, both tenses work, but the continuous version is prefered as long as you're talking around a temporary situation. The simple form is often used in these constructions, when it's considered as a permanent situation in this case.